# How can I access the session in my models and views in Django?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, view, models

What is the correct way to get information about the session in

- my models?
- my views?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the sessions middleware enabled, you can access `session` as a property of request which is passed into the view:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print request.session['my_session_key']
```

[django doc reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)